# Failed to compile eror

Tags: reactjs

Failed to compile
./src/serviceWorker.js
Error: [BABEL] D:\Projects\fgp-site\src\serviceWorker.js: Cannot find module '@babel/parser'
Require stack:

- D:\Projects\fgp-site\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules@babel\core\lib\index.js
- D:\Projects\fgp-site\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js
- D:\Projects\fgp-site\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- D:\Projects\fgp-site\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- D:\Projects\fgp-site\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- D:\Projects\fgp-site\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- D:\Projects\fgp-site\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- D:\Projects\fgp-site\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- D:\Projects\fgp-site\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
  at Function.assign ()
  at Generator.next ()

I work with React and wanted to create a transition between pages and, accordingly, the new page itself via Router

At first my index.js file looked like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9hGH.png)

After that, I realized that it needed to be changed, and after that I changed it to this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcu1Y.png)

In the first format, index.js does not show any errors for me, but what I need does not work, and when I change the idex code to another version, an error pops up this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTl20.png)

My Router file looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KisX7.png)

Comment: Questions should be in english, please check [ru.se].

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like the issue is with react-router. You've changed from using reportWebVitals to serviceWorker, and serviceWorker is what is throwing the error.

It looks like serviceWorker requires a Babel parser which is not in your package.json. You need to `npm install` it.